# Phonegap Android to other devices

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

If I build a Phonegap Android app, how do I deploy it to an iPhone and Blackberry? Is it as simple as clicking a button or do I need the Phone and Blackberry SDKs and have to move the webview files manually?

Comment: Oh ok, i misread it, i thought you mentioned you had an android app and how you would deploy it to the others.. sorry

Comment: no problem, i'm trying to figure out if its best to learn ios or android individually or use phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to rewrite the app another time, you just install the iOS SDK and create a new project then add the .jar files of Phonegap. Then you copy and paste your app files (the HTML, Javascript and CSS files to the new project which you built).

Comment: oh okay. So you still need the SDKs of all of the other devices then.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple indeed. But not as simple as that of clicking a button !

If you have developed it for android you will have an www directory which contains your index.html files with your js and images etc.

For android you would have used a js ( cordova.js / phonegap-android.js /similar ) through which you can access your android device specific things ( like buttons, camera, gps, etc ) .

If you are developing the same app for Blackberry , you need to replace the cordova.js with the same for blackberry ( which you can download from phonegap website )

And you need to setup a few things. It is pretty easy. [See this link](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/25653281/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap-BlackBerry%20with%20the%20Latest%20Environment)

And for iOs , you need a mac machine as only through Xcode you can develop.